# How to add popover template for directive

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there is way to add popover template for a directive. I am building a directive when user clicks on the element bootstrap popover should appear

here is my code

```
 ...
 restrict: 'A'
 template: '<a class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>'
 popoverTemplate: ".. html code .."
 link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
   $(element).popover
      html: yes
      title: attrs.title || 'Title'
      content: '... popoverTemplate ...' #this html should get form popoverTemplate
      container: 'body'
      placement: attrs.placement
 ...
```

is it right way? because popover has a html form.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the right way to do it.
I'd have a popover directive which u can use inside your directive's template. That popup directive should support transclusion, since you will pass an html.

In your directive's template:

```
<pop-over-directive ng-show="isPopupVisible">
    ... html here ....
</pop-over-directive>

... directive html here ...
<div ng-click="isPopupVisible=true"> ... </div>
```